# Why is { } Causing Latex to Make Space for Another Lettrine After \vskip?

Tags: braces, lettrine, drop-cap

The following code makes use of `\textbf{}` for illustrative purposes, but actually, `{}` will produce the same phenomenon.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}

\begin{document}
\Large

    \lettrine[lines=3,loversize=0.25,findent=2pt]{\color{red}{\initfamily{O}}}{}
    \textbf{Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? 
    \vskip 5pt
    \noindent Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc?}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

QUESTION: Can anyone explains why this happens? Remark: If I remove the `\textbf{` and the closing brace at the end of the code---everything is fine. However, if I just remove the `textbf` but keep both braces in place, the same strange thing occurs but without the bold of course.

Comment: why do you insist to use low-level tex commands like \vskip?  You are creating a second paragraph and it inherits the parshape settings of the first.

Comment: don't use vskip in latex (this is hardly the first time that has been mentioned)

Comment: but lettrine is making local assignments to the paragraph shape so if you start a new paragraph inside a group things naturally go wrong

Comment: vskip is not even mentioned in the official latex manual, and it has a syntax that is unlie any latex command, so it should be clear that it isn't latex.  I suggested`\\[5pt]` below but what is the space intended to signify. If it is a new paragraph then it should be marked with a blank line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\vskip` is a tex primitive that shouldn't be used in a LaTeX document (and lettrine can't really support starting paragraphs within a group) If you use the standard latex `\\[5pt]` construct to add 5pt after a forced line break (which is presumably the intention, although you don't say) it works without error. I get a larger initial than you show, for some reason?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}

\begin{document}
\Large

    \lettrine[lines=3,loversize=0.25,findent=2pt]{\color{red}{\initfamily{O}}}{}
    \textbf{Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc?\\[5pt] 
     Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc? Quid est hoc?}
    \end{document}
```